# Run a background task in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, background, background-task

im making an app where it has the users location and every 10 seconds theres a circle around the user that shrinks, ive got that part all working (using a timer with a time interval of 10 secs, then a .onRecieve on a text().) how do i make this timer run in the background when the user clicks the home button or turns off their phone, and how do i also make the circle keep shrinking while the phone is off, or update it to the right size when the app is opened again.

Comment: "or turns off their phone" -- you don't continue running a timer. You store the time that the event started and next time the app is opened, you see how much time has elapsed since that stored value.

Comment: @jnpdx how do i do that then? :)

Comment: Decide how you want to persist your data (UserDefaults and CoreData are two common options). Store the date. When the app next starts up (decide which method you want to use -- `init` in your `@main`, `onAppear` in your `ContentView`, etc), get the date out of the persisted store, and compare it to the current date.

Comment: @jnpdx Awesome thanks, could you submit it as an answer please?

Comment: you don't use the timer for background tasks. And really timers should be used with a great caution, in most cases they are used in place of proper event-drivern architecture

Comment: @PhilipTrevor -- I'm not comfortable submitting that as an answer, because the question (and the answer) are quite vague. You're welcome to use my comment and submit your own answer, though.

Comment: In addition to jnpdx’s observations, I’d also suggest that if you want to proactively notify the user at the allotted time, even if they are not running the app at the time, we often use [UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) framework, e.g., [Scheduling a notification locally from your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app).

Answer (score 1):

As [jnpdx said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73919418/run-a-background-task-in-swiftui#comment130519684_73919418):

> you don't continue running a timer. You store the time that the event started and next time the app is opened, you see how much time has elapsed since that stored value
>
> …
>
> Decide how you want to persist your data (UserDefaults and CoreData are two common options). Store the date. When the app next starts up (decide which method you want to use -- init in your @main, onAppear in your ContentView, etc), get the date out of the persisted store, and compare it to the current date.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Philip, I might suggest that you go ahead and [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so this is removed from the list of open questions.